# How should i make a new checkbox on button click by ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Add Skill</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <input  type='text' id='others' name='others' class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-3"/>
    <button type='submit' onclick='btn2' value='Add' class="btn btn-success"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code i want that when i click on the button it makes a new chekbox

Comment: Not clear enough. Do you want to create checkboxes depending on the response from ajax?

Comment: please paste your JS or ajax code also or better make js fiddle

Comment: can you please write down your btn2 function?

Comment: So have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: i don't have a JS or ajax code nor btn2 function i don't know about ajax @BilalZafar  John Christian

Comment: no @SougataBose

Comment: `i don't have a JS or ajax code`; then why why you have `on button click by ajax?` in your question?

Comment: so what should i use for ajax? @vijayP

Comment: Search for tutorials buddy. **GOOGLE** it.

Comment: I think you just want to create a button after receiving the response from ajax.
If not then please mention here that what is the use of this ajax in this question to get better and understandable answer from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add checkbox at runtime on `success` callback of your `AJAX` Request

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
      url : 'fila path',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success : function(response){ 
           $('#list').append("<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxname'/><br>");
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ajax success](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) callback function to add the checkbox.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
    // paste the below code in your success callback
    $('<input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" />').insertBefore(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Add Skill</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <input type='text' id='others' name='others' class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-3" />
    <button type='button' id='btn2' value='Add' class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above snippet will help you to add checkbox. I've added the checkbox on a simple button click, you can modify it with your ajax code. Hope this will help you.

**Updated** with ajax code,

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
       var self=this;
       $.ajax({
           url:'your_server_url',
           type:'POST', // let it is POST method
           success:function(response){
              $('<input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" />')
                    .insertBefore(self); // insert before your clicked button
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: OP wants the checkboxes to be created depending on ajax response.

Comment: when i write php in textbox, how will it become a name of that chekbox ?

Comment: @SougataBose Did you read *"You need to use ajax success callback function to add the checkbox."* in my answer.

Comment: Yes. But OP doesn't even know how to use **ajax**.

Comment: This is SO, only for helping in your code not a Freelance site(`can you write a code for me`).

Comment: @SougataBose He didn't mention that he doesn't know AJAX, if you are interested in training then help him for training. Otherwise there are lakhs of AJAX example available on Web just Google it.

Comment: lol. No need to be so hiper. I was just pointing out. OP needs to learn ajax first instead of asking here.

Comment: @AfzalKhan you can try my updated answer it might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#addCheckBox").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
            url : 'Url to get the ajax response',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
        data: {
           data: data,
        },
         success: function( response ) {
         $('#others').append("<input type='checkbox' name="checkboxCreated"/>");
        }
        });
});
```